# Disable hibernate fetching dynamically

Tags: hibernate

I have currently implemented a row level security, where tables that need to be secure have columns for a Owner, Group and Unix-style permissions.

What is currently happening is every time we request an entity through hibernate, we add a custom criterion verifying if the user has access to the data. This custom criterion is also added on every create.Alias() to make sure that contact with other tables is also secured.

The problem is our model has multiple entities with @manyToOne relationships and since those entities are fetched automatically, there is no way to secure the nested entities.

What I am looking for is a way to either:

1. Make it so that only the entities added through a create.Alias() are fetched

   OR
2. Gain dynamic control over what is fetched by hibernate

Those seem to be the two ways that would not imply a huge code refactoring
of our project.

Is this something that can be done or is there any other way to enforce our security throughout?

P.S: Never returning nested entities is unfortunately impossible as it is needed client side. Also we tried using max_fetch_depth 0, but even though the nested entities were not requested in our initial queries, hibernate seems to make multiple subsequent queries to complete the entity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm at the researched-but-not-used stage of essentially this for my own project, and I believe [filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html#objectstate-filters) are what you want. If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, you define a filter along with your schema, enable it and give it parameters programmatically when you open the session, and for the duration of the session Hibernate will pretend objects that don't pass the filter don't exist. In addition to securing the relationship-based fetches, this will also remove the need to manually add security checks to every query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We did look into filter unfortunately it seems that it would require to add such a filter to every current relationship and future ones. That would mean that if a future programmer adds several other models and forget to include the filter, the entity would not be secure. It's seems quite a bit risky. Also currently our requests to the database are almost all regrouped into a generic "service" class, so adding the security on every query is not a problem.

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I am really out of ideas on this situation and I think hibernate filters might be possible as a temporary solution indeed. The problem though is that it seems I cannot filter an Entity using the ManyToOne nested Entity properties. If you happen to have found a way around that in your own project, here is another stackoverflow post I made about this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437164/hibernate-manytoone-filter-on-base-entity

Comment: @jemag I'm working on it. Filters are increasingly striking me as a half-assed slapdash implementation of an idea that really deserves more. They are extremely limited in both scope of application and scope of available properties to filter on.