# Hibernate manyToOne filter on base entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity "Event" that has a ManyToOne relationship with the entity "Organization". So an Organization can have multiple events.

What I originally wanted to do was to filter the entity Event using a property of the Organization entity. So basically when I fetch events, only return the events that have an Organization.code= :codeParam.

To accomplish that I implemented a hibernate filter with :

```
@FilterDef(name="codeFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="codeParam", type="string" ) )
```

...

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Organization_Id")
@Filter(name="codeFilter", condition=" code = :codeParam")
private Organization organization;
```

...

```
Filter hibernateFilter = sess.enableFilter("codeFilter");
hibernateFilter.setParameter("codeParam", "hola");
```

Unfortunately according to a post from the Hibernate Team on the hibernate forums, this is not possible :

> A Hibernate data filter does not change the multiplicity of an association. By definition it therefore does not filter many-to-one, one-to-one, or any load() or get() operation.
>
> What is it supposed to do, return NULL instead of an instance? NULL does not mean FILTERED, it means NULL. You guys are using filters wrong.

So my question is : is there any way to filter the base entity ("Event") with a condition on the entity from a manyToOne relationship (Organization.code= :codeParam)?

I need this to be enforced every time there is a fetch of events, so a solution using the already existing hibernate filters or something similar would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT1: The question is a simple example of what needs to be done on a significantly bigger scale. Basically, we want to add security to all our Entities and their own nested Entities through the use of a globally defined filter on a Unix permissions row that all our tables have.

Comment: Why don't you just add a join and a where condition to your query? Something like `"from Event e join e.organization o where o.code = :codeParam"`.

Comment: What about a NamedQuery and you enforce that condition into your DAO.

Comment: @Thomas This might sound a bit complicated, but we have a "GenericDataService" where all our fetching of objects or list of objects is centralized. So we fetch objects in a generic manner. We have a lot of classes in our model with a lot of manyToOne relationships. To add a condition to the query, we would have to use reflection to parse the object and add a condition for each manyToOne relationships contained in the class. This would add a significant overhead and is unfortunately not possible for us.Mor detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324159/disable-hibernate-fetching-dynamically

Comment: @medveshonok117 I am sorry I'll try to edit the question to be more specific, but basically a NamedQuery would indeed work but the problem is that we want to use the filter to add security to all our entities. With a globally defined filter, I can simple add the same filter to all our classes. With a NamedQuery, I would have to manually write the NamedQuery for every entity in our model according to their ManyToOne relationships. Also, if the class change, NamedQueries would have to be changed too. So it would only work if it were possible to have some kind of dynamic/class adjusting NamedQ.

Comment: It appears that what you really want is [Multi-tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) with a discriminator column. This is apparently planned but not yet implemented in Hibernate 5. EclipseLink already has it according to their docs, and I'm considering switching because of that.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: Do not do this, it is dependent on Hibernate internals and prone to breaking on schema changes, and possibly on variations in individual query setup.

Set Hibernate to show its generated sql, run the query you want to filter (in this case, loading some `Event` objects), and check what name it assigns to the join used for fetching the related `Organization`. For example, the generated sql might include `inner join Organization someNameHere on this_.Organization_Id = someNameHere.OrganizationId`. Then apply the filter, not to the association, but to the `Event` class, with condition `"someNameHere.code = :codeParam"`.

This is, unfortunately, the only way I've been able to find to filter one class by the properties of an associated class.

I'm trying to make a more robust solution, but it's a complex issue and I'm still in the research stage for that. I expect it will use code generation (through an annotation processor) and programmatic modification of Hibernate's mapping information on startup, but I'm not sure what else yet.

Comment: nice research. Have you found a new solution finally ?